# select data from multiple table with specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables, user, blog and status.

here is ***[sqlFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f01f2/13/0)*** of my example database

user is the main table where userId and other info of user is store. I want that when I search from table user, the query should also get data from other two tables with specific userId.But only one row from blog which has maximum views,if one blog has same views then which row has max bogId that should come. and sort by views desc, if there is no blog with that userId then sort by should  status id.

result comes as i want but, can someone simplify this the query.
sorry for bad English.

Comment: is there more than one status row for each user?  is there always at least one?  if there are multiple ones, which do you want?  or all? which columns in blog and status do you actually want returned?

Comment: this query is more complex than it needs to be for example the `WHERE` can be reduced to not use the subquery in since you already have `user` table data. I am sure more can be simplified. It's best if you have sample data set up in sqlFiddle and ask for what results you expect to see. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this anything like what you want ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN blog b ON u.userId = b.userId
LEFT JOIN status s ON u.userId = s.userId
WHERE MATCH(u.firstName, u.lastName, u.userName) AGAINST('harry')
GROUP BY u.userId
ORDER BY b.views
```